# Debug API requests in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, api-design

I have a local API call, which uses some of the .py code.
But unfortunately, the debugging is not working, it does not come to the breakpoints, simply run the entire code.
Here would be an example of the code:

```py
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/analyze/recipesegment/'
params = {'Id': '123', 'Language': 'en'}
headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'X-API-Key': '123'}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
```

The results are correct, but it does not make a breakpoint at the place of the code where I want.
I know that I can make it in PyCharm via creating a Configuration for API calls. Then can actually call from the Frontend/Swagger.